# Gradle Problem When Importing Flutter Project From Git

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter, build.gradle

I imported a Flutter Project from this git repo: https://github.com/gligerglg/geodropin (website: https://itsallwidgets.com/geodropin) by copying the HTTPS, then go to Android Studio -> Check out Project from Version Control -> Git. When I open the project and try to run, this error appear:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/Users/phuctruong/AndroidStudioProjects/geodropin/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/phuctruong/AndroidStudioProjects/geodropin/android/app/build.gradle' line: 45

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> For input string: "1.01"

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
  Command: /Users/phuctruong/AndroidStudioProjects/geodropin/android/gradlew app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

I assume this has something to do with my gradle version and the project's gradle version? I'm a newbie to Flutter so my understanding of gradle is limited. When I check gradle-wrapper.property it said i'm using gradle 4.10.2

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [16th](https://github.com/gligerglg/geodropin/blob/master/android/app/build.gradle#L16) line of app/build.gradle you will see that the number in a string is of float type. VersionCode should always be integer. Check this out https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

You can remove this error by just changing it to positive integer value like this :

```
flutterVersionCode = '1'
```

Now this problem is resolved but however you will get another error related to androidX but thats different question.

Error would be :

> BUILD FAILED in 10s
>   ******************************************************************************************* The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities
>   in this Flutter app. See [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration) for more information on
>   the problem and how to fix it.
>   ******************************************************************************************* Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

For this issue you need to migrate the project to androidX,

add it in android/gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Or if its already there, Check this migration [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility) for more info.

Or nothing works, you can ask another question.